# r- call function inside for loop alternative

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

```
my_function <- function(n){}

result = list()
for(i in 0:59){
    result[i] = my_function(i)
}
write.csv(result, "result.csv")
```

New to R, read that for-loops are bad in R, so is there an alternative to what I'm doing? I'm basically trying to call my_function with a parameter that's increasing, and then write the results to a file.

**Edit**
Sorry I didn't specify that I wanted to use some function of i as a parameter for my_function, 12 + (22*i) for example. Should I create a list of values and then called lapply with that list of values?

Comment: That is old hear-say from the S-Plus days (where they had `for` vs `For`) and generally not true.  First, get it right.  Then worry about style.

Comment: Updated my answer per your edit

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops are fine in R, but they're syntactically inefficient in a lot of use cases, especially simple ones. The `apply` family of functions usually makes a good substitute.

```
result <- lapply(0:59, my_function)
write.csv(result, "result.csv")
```

Depending on what your function's output is, you might want `sapply` rather than `lapply`.

Edit:

Per your update, you could do it as you say, creating the vector of values first, or you could just do something like:

```
lapply(12+(22*0:59), my_function)
```

Comment: More concise, but probably indistinguishable performance-wise as long as `my_function()` has some actual cost.